# printing rows as well in a function output

Tags: r

So, I made this function in R.

```
> reps <- function(s, n) paste(rep(s, n), collapse = "") # repeat s n times
> 
> find.string <- function(strinag, th = 3, len = floor(nchar(string)/th)) {
+     for(k in len:1) {
+         pat <- paste0("(.{", k, "})", reps("\\1", th-1))
+         r <- regexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)
+         if (attr(r, "capture.length") > 0) break
+     }
+     if (r > 0) substring(string, r, r + attr(r, "capture.length")-1) else ""
+ }
```

This function basically is used for finding out patterns. For example: If I input, the sequence as 100100100, then it will output, "100" ( the maximal length pattern satisfying the minimum threshold = 3). However, if a string such as 100110 is passed, it outputs nothing since no continuous pattern is being formed.

Now, I applied this function over a file(1000's of rows) having format like this.

```
    V1  V2  V3   V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10  V11  
0   2    4   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0     0
1   1    2   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1     0  
2   ....................................
3
4
5
```

Now, after that, I did so that the numbers in different columns(V3-V11) get passed as a string to the function that I made.

input <- do.call(cbind, df[,3:ncol(df)])

and then,

```
 apply(input, 1, function(x) print(gsub(", ","",toString(x)))).
```

However, this just produces the output as,

Output file:

```
110  
01
10 
10
```

What I want is, that the first two columns of the row which produces the output should also get included in the output file.

So, let's say row 1 produces an output, therefore, it should be included in the output file as,

```
 2  4  100
 1  2  10

................
```

What changes should I make to my existing code in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data you are writing to the output file is stored in some variable, lets say `x`. Since you applied a function across all the rows of your data, the order of the output and the rows will be the same. Thus you can just cbind the first two columns back in

```
write.table(cbind(df[,1:2], x), "outfile.txt")
```

And that should properly restore the original line beginnings.